# problem on $S_n$, quotient and isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

> Does there exist a finite group $G$ with normal subgroups $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that$N_1 \cong S_5$, $N_2\cong S_7$, $G/N_1\cong S_{42}$ and $G/N_2\cong S_{41}$?

Consider $N_1<N_2$. (Edit: Wrong since $N_2$ cannot have normal subgroup of order equal to that of $N_1$) $$S_{41}\cong G/N_2\cong \frac{G/N_1}{N_2/N_1}$$. I do not know structure of $S_7/S_5$.

The case $N_1\nless N_2$ remains.

On the other hand I tried to find $G$. One way to find example of a group with multiple properties is to consider multiple groups each with one property and consider their direct product. But $G=S_5\oplus S_7 \oplus H$, for some $H$, fails.

The fact that $41$ is prime may be useful.

The problem has many subgroups which makes it complicated. Please give a hint. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that alternating groups (of degree at least 5) are simple?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I did consider it, but for all the $S_n$'s in this problem, the subgroups of $S_n$ which we consider have index $\neq 2$ in $S_n$ ($[N_2:N_1]=42$, $[G/N_1:N_2/N_1]=42$). Please tell where to use $A_n$

Comment: Is $S_5$ a normal subgroup of $S_7$?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Sorry. (I did not check my attempt rigorously because I was far from a solution yet.) So this eliminates the case $N_1<N_2$. The case $N_1 \nless N_2$ boils down to $N_1\cap N_2=\{e\}$ hence $G\cong S_5\oplus S_7 \oplus H$ for some $H$, which, as noted earlier, fails. Thanks!